# Dollar amount on free item automatically appears when pinning

Tags: pinterest

I am implementing Pinterest on my site and we have encountered a problem.  Pinterest will automatically put a graphic on the picture for an item if it sees a monetary value in the description.

We have a free activity that we would like people to be able to pin (via 'pin it' button) called "The $100 game".  Pinterest automatically puts the $100 graphic on the pin which makes it look like our game costs $100 when it is actually free.

Any way around this?  Short of changing the name of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest is still new and I don't think there is a way to escape $ sign to be treated as text and not price. If I were you I would post that on their forum so that they know of the issue, but other than that I guess you have to figure something else out.